# Writing a file on webserver's disk using HTML and/or JS only?

Tags: html, server-side

I am wondering if it would be possible to have a HTML page output a small text file to the webserver's disk.

I'd like to avoid setting up PHP or another similar dynamic page framework because I only have one single text file to write (less than 200 bytes in content).

The data could be passed in a HTTP POST and it is two parameters only (phone number and language).

Is there any way to do this or will I have to install and setup PHP?
I appreciate it would be easier with PHP but it kind of removes the challenge ;)

Thank you for your help!

Comment: If you're using an opensource webserver you could edit the source to save, that'd be a challenge! :P

Comment: You need something server-side to handle this.  I suppose you could just write your own Bash CGI script.